# How to return an array of base64 objects from ExpressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to read a bunch of image files (JPEGs) from a folder using ExpressJS and return each image as a base64 encoded data using an array. So the end result should be an array of base64 objects. I've below code but it's not working as I get the below error..

```
data.getListOfImages = async function (res, next) {
    let retVal = { success: true };
   
    try {
        fs.readdir('./images/', function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
            files.forEach(file => {
             fs.readFile('./images/'+file, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err // Fail if the file can't be read.
                
                cardList[cntr]=data
                logger.info(file);
                cntr++
                
              })
            
          });
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg:base64'})
          res.end(cardList);
          next(null, { success: true, error: null, result: res });
        })
    } 
    catch (error) {
      logger.info(
        "addJob ==> Error while extracting image files : " + error
      );
      retVal = { success: false, error: error };
      next(error, null);
    }
  };
```

I get below error ....

```
"error":{"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"},"exception":true,"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: The \"chunk\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Array\nTypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]
```

any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: which line of that code throws the error - also, it makes no sense to have `'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg:base64'` since the content type is simply an array of strings

Comment: Last line next(null, { success: true, error: null, result: res }); once I changed that to next(null, cardList); the error has gone assuming it was due to me writing the response object and returning it as a part of a JSON object earlier though now I am getting an empty array back which still doesn't serve the purpose. I am suspecting this has something to do with the way files are read in async manner i.e. an empty response getting sent immediately while the file reading is still in progress within the loop. Any idea how to get around this? i.e. await till all files are read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs this solution, the below code works.

```
data.getListOfImages = async function (res, next) {
    let retVal = { success: true };
    var cardList = [];
    try {
      fs.readdir(folderPath, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).send("Error reading folder");
          return;
        }
        files.forEach((file) => {
          const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
          const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
          const base64Content = fileContent.toString("base64");
          cardList.push(base64Content);
          
          cntr++;
        });
        

        next(null, cardList);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      logger.info("Error while extrcting image files : " + error);
      retVal = { success: false, error: error };
      next(error, null);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your await this:

```
data.getListOfImages = async function (res, next) {
  let retVal = { success: true };
  
  try {
      const files = await fs.promises.readdir('./images/');
      // Returns array of promises
      const readAsyncResult = files.map(async file => fs.promises.readFile('./images/'+file, {encoding: 'base64'}))
      const cardList = await Promise.All(readAsyncResult);

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg:base64'})
      res.end(cardList);
  } 
  catch (error) {
    logger.info(
      "addJob ==> Error while extracting image files : " + error
    );
    retVal = { success: false, error: error };
    next(error, null);
  }
};
```

Note that there are some subtle differences between [Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Promise.AllSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) in the way that they handle errors.

Comment: Thanks ImaCoden. Now I a, getting an error using your code despite I am passing a valid function for the callback... i.e. nothing has changed in my controller call to this service...  {"level":"info","message":"(services/cardService.js:28) getListOfImages ==> Error while extracting image files : TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined"}

Comment: Updated the code sample to use `fs.promises.` sub library. This should resolve that issue.

Comment: Thanks. While it went pass that statement, it fails now at the fs.readFile() call with the below error as it expects a callback so I've changed it to below code. while it gets through the execution and I can see the data content in the log, I still get an empty array of results in Postman   

`// Returns array of promises
        const readAsyncResult =  files.map( async file => fs.readFile('./images/'+file, {encoding: 'base64'}, (err, data)=>{
          logger.info("+++ Reading file..."+file);
          logger.info("+++ Content is..."+data);
        })) `